# Did I use the Weierstrass M-Test Correctly on $\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to make sure I am using the Weierstrass test correctly. So, on the following expression: $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}, -1 \le x \le 1$$

I looked at it this way. First I checked to see what happens at -1 and 1. The "plug in" test gets me a limit of 1/2 at x=1 and n=1, and a limit of 1/2 at x=-1 and n=1. All-righty then, we do a little L'Hôpital's rule: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  f_n(x) = \frac{\frac{d}{dn}(x)}{\frac{d}{dn}(1+ nx^2)}= \frac {0}{x^2}=0 $$

So I know this converges to zero. But does it do so uniformly? Well, I can see that this function has a bound at x=1/2. So I will use $\frac{1}{1+n}$ as my M-function. Giving us: 
$M_k = \frac{1}{1+n},$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n}$.

$\frac{1}{1+n}$ is always going to be smaller than $\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ for any n with a particular x. That's becaue x will be between -1 and 1 and $x^2$ is therefore going to be less than 1, so (as someone pointed out below, thanks!) $1+nx^2$ is always going to be less than $1+n$. So we can say $$ \left| \frac{x}{1+nx^2} \right| \ge \frac{1}{1+n}$$ for all n. In addition to that, $\frac{1}{1+n} \lt \infty$ for all n. So we DO NOT have uniform convergence.

Did I get it right?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few errors here. First of all, it is not true that $\displaystyle |\frac{x}{1+nx^2}|\leqslant \frac{1}{1+n}$ without more words (if it is even true), since $1+nx^2\leqslant 1+n$. Also, $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{n+1}=\infty$.

Comment: I was thinking that since we start with $n=1$, if you plug it into those and put any x there, $\frac{1}{1+n}$ is going to maximize at 1/2. Meanwhile $\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ when you increase n, the upper limits actually go down from there. I graphed it to check.

Comment: And lord knows if there are other errors by all means tell me.

Comment: And I think I see the errors I made. So folks let me know if I got better...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the $M$-test is usually used to prove convergence, not the other way around.

First notice that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0 \quad \forall x \in [-1,1].$$

Consider $\left \| \frac{x}{1+nx^2} \right \|_{\infty}$.

Taking the derivative we find that $x = \pm 1/\sqrt{n}$ are the only critical points. Plugging this back into $f_n(x)$, we find that $f_n(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) = \pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \to 0$.

Therefore we conclude the sequence $(f_n)_{n \geq 1}$ indeed converges uniformly to $0$. Notice this is true for any $x \in \Bbb R$, not restricted to $x \in [-1,1].$